# Переход из Fragment в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Ребята, как сделать, чтобы при запуске приложении в Activity был один Fragment, а при нажатии на кнопку  появлялся другой Fragment, при этом 1й удалялся.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для динамической смены фрагментов используйте метод `replace()`.

**Например:**

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment(); // Фрагмент, которым собираетесь заменить первый фрагмент

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); // Или getSupportFragmentManager(), если используете support.v4
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); // Заменяете вторым фрагментом. Т.е. вместо метода `add()`, используете метод `replace()`
transaction.addToBackStack(null); // Добавляете в backstack, чтобы можно было вернутся обратно

transaction.commit(); // Коммитете
```

Более подробно можно почитать в оффициальной документации: [Раз](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace), [Два](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29).

А также посмотрите данный [урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/175-urok-105-android-3-fragments-dinamicheskaja-rabota.html).

Answer (score 3):

При запуске добавляете один фрагмент. При нажатии на кнопку добавляете другой фрагмент. Можете даже оба фрагмента однаково помещать в коде:

```
Fragment newFragment = new YourFragment(); //YourFragment заменить на нужный
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment); //fragment_container заменить на Ваш id контейнера
transaction.commit();
```